# Yii: 2 models with the same code for beforeValidate

Tags: php, yii, content-management-system, yii-cmodel

I have a Yii app, and within 2 of the models, I have the code for the beforeValidation method.

Does yii have a solution for this, or should I create a component and use parameters for this common code?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a class which both of your model extends:

```
class CommonClass extends CActiveRecord
{

    public function beforeValidate(){
       ...
    }

}

class A extends CommonClass{
}

class B extends CommonClass{
}
```

Or you could define a behavior and add this behavior to both of your models!

```
class YourBehavior extends CActiveRecordBehavior
{
    public function beforeValidate($event)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class A extends CActiveRecord{
    public function behaviors(){
    return array(
        'YourBehavior' => array(
            'class' => 'components.YourBehavior',
        ),      
    );
}
}

class B extends CActiveRecord{
    public function behaviors(){
    return array(
        'YourBehavior' => array(
            'class' => 'components.YourBehavior',
        ),      
    );
}
}
```

Comment: this is what i was also thinking about, but i thought that yii has a prebuilt solution for this case

Comment: Hum for what I know about Yii those are the only solutions that I'm aware of. But declaring a behavior is really easy, I don't know what 'prebuilt solution' easier than this you could have in mind!

Comment: weel, i was just wondering, this is nothing special, its normal environment with classes